# Connection timed out ; no servers could be reached error

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have configured a DNS server in Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
But when I type   "dig -x 8.8.8.8"    from any client's machine while changing its nameserver in   /etc/resolv/conf file   to the IP address of my DNS server which is 192.168.0.192 and also changing its dns-nameserver in   /etc/network/interfaces  to address of my DNS server, I am not able to get any response from my clients machine.
I am getting this error on clients machine " Connection timed out: no servers could be reached".

Moreover When I type " ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 " on clients machine , 
I get a response " .

Can anybody please help me to make my Clients machine work properly and go through my DNS server on which I have set BIND to act as a Caching or Forwarding DNS server.

Note : I have done configuration for BIND server from this website 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04